# How to turn on display with mouse move but not with VK_SPACE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, display

This code disables 1 display out of 2. The task is to turn it on not from `VK_SPACE`, but from mouse movement.

I tried to do it through `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, but so far nothing has worked. I don't really understand how this problem can be implemented.

If there is an opportunity to implement this topic, I will be very grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")

#define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)
#define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)

const BYTE PowerMode = 0xD6;  // VCP Code defined in VESA Monitor Control Command Set (MCCS) standard
const DWORD PowerOn = 0x01;
const DWORD PowerOff = 0x04;

// Monitor description struct
struct MonitorDesc
{
    HANDLE hdl;
    DWORD power;
};

// Monitor enumeration callback
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    std::vector<MonitorDesc>* pMonitors = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MonitorDesc>*>(dwData);

    DWORD nMonitorCount;
    if (GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &nMonitorCount))
    {
        PHYSICAL_MONITOR* pMons = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[nMonitorCount];

        if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, nMonitorCount, pMons))
        {
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < nMonitorCount; i++)
            {
                MonitorDesc desc;
                desc.hdl = pMons[i].hPhysicalMonitor;

                pMonitors->push_back(desc);
            }
        }
        delete[] pMons;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// Switch monitor power
void MonitorSwitch(MonitorDesc& monitor, DWORD mode)
{
    if (monitor.power == mode)
        return;

    SetVCPFeature(monitor.hdl, PowerMode, mode);
    monitor.power = mode;
}

int main()
{
    // Скрытие консоли 

    HWND hWnd;
    AllocConsole();
    hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);

    std::vector<MonitorDesc> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MonitorEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors));

    // Init
    for (auto& monitor : monitors)
    {
        monitor.power = PowerOn;
    }

    // Here select the first one monitor as example
    MonitorDesc targetMonitor = monitors[0];

    while (1)
    {
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                // turn off
                if (targetMonitor.power == PowerOn)
                    MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOff);

        }
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_SPACE))
                // turn on
                MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOn);
        }
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                return 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you move the mouse, there will be many WM_MOUSEMOVE events sent to your program. Are you sure use this event?

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT yes i need it. But if i can do this with another command it will be fine. I need just to turn on display whit mouse. On 1 of display advertising is played and the second should go out in order to save energy

Comment: I see what you mean, you want the monitor where the mouse is on to be on, and the other monitors to be off.

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT exactly

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT its posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) to get the real-time mouse position and perform an energy-saving operation when the mouse is over the edge of a monitor.Here is my code，I commented the code in detail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")

#define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)
#define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)


const BYTE PowerMode = 0xD6;  // VCP Code defined in VESA Monitor Control Command Set (MCCS) standard
const DWORD PowerOn = 0x01;
const DWORD PowerOff = 0x04;

// Monitor description struct
struct MonitorDesc
{
    HANDLE hdl;
    DWORD power;
};

// Monitor enumeration callback
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    std::vector<MonitorDesc>* pMonitors = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MonitorDesc>*>(dwData);

    DWORD nMonitorCount;
    if (GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &nMonitorCount))
    {
        PHYSICAL_MONITOR* pMons = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[nMonitorCount];

        if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, nMonitorCount, pMons))
        {
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < nMonitorCount; i++)
            {
                MonitorDesc desc;
                desc.hdl = pMons[i].hPhysicalMonitor;

                pMonitors->push_back(desc);
            }
        }
        delete[] pMons;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// Switch monitor power
void MonitorSwitch(MonitorDesc& monitor, DWORD mode)
{
    if (monitor.power == mode)
        return;

    SetVCPFeature(monitor.hdl, PowerMode, mode);
    monitor.power = mode;
}


int main()
{

    // Скрытие консоли 

    HWND hWnd;
    AllocConsole();
    hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);

    std::vector<MonitorDesc> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MonitorEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors));

    // Init
    for (auto& monitor : monitors)
    {
        monitor.power = PowerOn;
    }

    // Here select the first one monitor as example
    MonitorDesc targetMonitor = monitors[0];
    int currentMonitorID = 0; //need start this exe in monitors[0] 

    //Mouse position
    LONG zx = -1;
    LONG zy = -1;
    POINT ptB = { 0, 0 };

    while (1)
    {
        /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /*-                          -                                  -*/
        /*-                          -                                  -*/
        /*-                          -                                  -*/
        /*-     monitors[0]          -             monitors[1]          -*/
        /*-                          -                                  -*/
        /*-                          -                                  -*/
        /*-                          -                                  -*/
        /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /*                       {1919,1079}                             */

        LPPOINT xy = &ptB;   //Location variables
        GetCursorPos(xy);    //Gets the current mouse position        

        //If the mouse moves, (i.e. the current coordinates change to print out the coordinates) print out the coordinates.
        if ((zx != xy->x) || (zy != xy->y))
        {
            //Here you need to test the edge of your monitor[0]
            //After Test, delete this and Hide the console by ShowWindow(hWnd, 0)
            printf("x=%d,y=%d\n", xy->x, xy->y);
        }

        //The coordinate in the lower right corner of my monitor is {1919,1079}
        if (xy->x > 1919 && currentMonitorID == 0)
        {
            currentMonitorID = 1;
            MonitorSwitch(monitors[1], PowerOn);
            MonitorSwitch(monitors[0], PowerOff);
        }
        else if ( xy->x <= 1919 && currentMonitorID == 1)
        {
            currentMonitorID = 0;
            MonitorSwitch(monitors[0], PowerOn);
            MonitorSwitch(monitors[1], PowerOff);
        }

        /*if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                // turn off
                if (targetMonitor.power == PowerOn)
                    MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOff);

        }
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_SPACE))
                // turn on
                MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOn);
        }*/
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                return 0;
        }

    }
}
```