# turn off only one specific monitor | Python

Tags: python, winapi, screen, ctypes, monitor

I have three screens and I know how to turn on/off all screens with this code:

```
import time
import ctypes
import win32api, win32con
def screen_off():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, 2)
def screen_on():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, -1)
    move_cursor()
def move_cursor():
    x, y = (0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y)
```

But Is it possible to identify all monitors connected to the system and choose which ones to turn off or on? So for instance you have three monitors and only want to turn off/on the lateral two. Would that be programmatically possible through Phyton code?

Comment: The specific implementation of python can refer to the winapi used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030204/how-to-turn-on-display-with-mouse-move-but-not-with-vk-space/71031869#71031869), use [EnumDisplayMonitors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) to enumerate the displays, use [SetVCPFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setvcpfeature) to control the display on and off.

Comment: Where did you get those values passed to *SendMessageW* from?